# What is the difference in intent between the serializers in FCL?

Tags: .net, serialization, fcl

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154198/what-are-the-differences-between-the-xmlserializer-and-binaryformatter) does a good job of explaining the difference in *functionality* between the serializers. `BinaryFormatter` is fast, `XmlSerializer` is interoperable, etc. I know that.

But what is the difference in *intent*? What use-case was each class designed for?

In particular:

- Why did they decide to make `XmlSerializer` blind for private data, when `BinaryFormatter` sees it fast enough (via the supposedly-slow reflection)
- Why did they make 3 separate XML serializers - `XmlSerializer`, `SoapFormatter` and `DataContractSerializer`?
- Why are some opt-in and some opt-out?
- Why did they make the interfaces so inconsistent? E.g. XmlSerializer doesn't provide an `OnDeserializedCallback` equivalent. Another example - XmlSerializer uses `IsNullable` `[XmlIgnore]` for what BinarySerializer uses `[OptionalField]` and `[NonSerialized]`.

Answer (score 0):

XML Serialization is used to create a specific XML structure, and allows you to change how the object is serialized - what the XMl looks like (if you use attributes or nodes, etc).

Binary Serialization "sees" the private members because it just takes the in memory structure of the object and writes it to to disk.  Very fast, but not interoperable, especially with slightly different object structures (like a new version of your app attempting to deserialize an older binary file).

The SoapFormatter and DataContractSerializer are used for communication between .NET components, normally a tiered application - with DataContractSerializer used in WCF, and SoapFormatter used for the older SOAP utilities.