# C# Serialization practices of object with custom types

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, binary-serialization

I've created some custom types for example:

```
public class Temperature
{
    protected double _celcius;

    public Temperature(){}

    public Temperature(double celcius)
    {
        _celcius = celcius;
    }

    public double Celcius
    {
        //sets & returns temperature in Celcius
    }

    public double Fahrenheit
    {
        //sets & returns temperature in Fahrenheit
    }
}
```

and a similar one for `Mass`, etc.

I also have a custom object, for example `Planet`, which uses these custom types as properties.

```
[Serializable]
public class Planet
{
    public int PositionFromSun;
    public Mass Mass;
    public Temperature Temperature;
}
```

What is the best practice for serializing `Planet` in this case considering that `Mass` and `Temperature` may change slightly in the future (e.g. adding `Kelvin` to `Temperature`)? Should I have `Mass` and `Temperature` inheriting from a custom interface of something like `IQuantity`.

Comment: If you're serializing with the BinaryFormatter you don't have to care about public properties, it'll serialize only fields (in your case _celcius). Moreover if you want to save your data to use the default formatter isn't a good idea because of its "proprietary" format and the way it handles versions.

Comment: So you're saying that as long as I keep `_celcius` in there, it doesn't matter what I do with the surrounding code?

Could you please expand a little on your second sentence, please?

Comment: Yes, you can add as many public properties as you need. For comparison take a look at this post here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154198/what-are-the-differences-between-the-xmlserializer-and-binaryformatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see @Adriano's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699245/c-sharp-serialization-practices-of-object-with-custom-types#comment13890086_10699245). This is what I needed.

> Yes, you can add as many public properties as you need. For comparison take a look at this post here on SO: [What are the differences between the XmlSerializer and BinaryFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154198/what-are-the-differences-between-the-xmlserializer-and-binaryformatter)

Answer (score 0):

Binary serialization is quite picky about properties being added and removed to types. If you use a version tolerant serializer (eg xml based serialisers) you'll be able to reliably serialize / deserialise between versions of classes.

You may want to consider using [protobuf.Net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for your serialization - it is mature, very very quick and version tolerant.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at protobuf.Net!