# Differences between XML.Serialization and Runtime.Serialization

Tags: serialization

Can anyone explain the differences between System.XML.Serialization and System.Runtime.Serialization ?

Comment: [this answer mentions the difference between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154429/2431645)

Answer (score 1):

The **System.Xml.Serialization** namespace contains classes that are used to serialize objects into XML format documents or streams.
The **System.Runtime.Serialization** namespace contains classes that can be used for serializing and de-serializing objects.

Comment: For Further you can use these links [System.Xml.Serialization Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx),                      [System.Runtime.Serialization Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.aspx)